# trying for user authentication for a web app project in .Net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to build a bank web app as part of our course project, but I get this error regarding user :

> System.InvalidOperationException: The model backing the
>   'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed since the database was
>   created

Consider using Code First [Migrations to update the database](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269). When I try to migrate it gives an error :

```
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.WishLists_dbo.Accounts_AccountId".

 The conflict occurred in database "db_9b1d65373e9b4f0faa8eecf677186e7d",

table "dbo.Accounts", column 'Id'
```

Comment: Check that there is not existing data in the database that is conflicting with the FK constraint causing the creation to fail.

Comment: I deleted the connected data base, but even then it shows the same error when I try to update the project using Update-Database

Comment: Did you deleted your Migration history table?

Comment: Yes....I successfully solved that step. I deleted than removed that foreign key then updated the database. It works now.

Comment: I am working on putting user authentication so that only a user can see the details. Plz help.

Comment: Yes, you can create your authentication filter or use [Custom Forms Authentication in ASP.NET MVC Application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/578374/AplusBeginner-splusTutorialplusonplusCustomplusF) hope this help you!